# Why does find -regex not accept my regex?

Tags: regex, find

I want to select some files that are matching a regular expression.
Files are for example:

```
4510-88aid-50048-INA.txt
4510-88nid-50048-INA.txt
xxxx-05xxx-xxxxx-INA.txt
```

I want all files that match this regex:

```
.*[\w]{4}-05(?!aid)[\w]{3}-[\w]{5}-INA\.txt
```

In my opinion this have to be `xxxx-05xxx-xxxxx-INA.txt` in the case above.
Using some tool like [RegexTester](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html), everything works perfect.
Using the bash command `find -regex` doesn´t seem to work for me. 
My question is, why?

I can't figure it out, I am using:

```
find /some/path -regex ".*[\w]{4}-05(?!aid)[\w]{3}-[\w]{5}-INA\.txt" -exec echo {} \;
```

But nothing is printed... Any ideas?

```
$ uname -a
Linux debmu838 2.6.5-7.321-smp #1 SMP Mon Nov 9 14:29:56 UTC 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Not all regex engines are created equal. Syntaxes and features change. I'm not sure that `find` supports java regex syntax (which is what you're testing with). It probably doesn't.

Comment: Why do you have the `.*` at the beginning? Doesn't look like you need that.

Comment: the .* was for the filepath that was before my filename in the example above

Comment: There are quite some regular expression syntaxes supported by `find` (via the `-regextype` argument, but none of them supports (negative) lookahead assertions. So using perl or some other external RE engine as a pipe seems like in jm666's answer seems to be the best idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bash4+ and perl

```
ls /some/path/**/*.txt | perl -nle 'print if /^[\w]{4}-05(?!aid)[\w]{3}-[\w]{5}-INA\.txt/'
```

you should have in your .profile `shopt -s globstar`

Answer (score 6):

I pretty much ditto the other answers: Find's `-regex` switch can't emulate everything in Perl's regex, However, here's something you can try...

Take a look at the [find2perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/find2perl.html) command. That program can take a typical find statement, and give you a Perl program equivalent for it. I don't believe `-regex` is recognized by `find2perl` (It's not in the standard Unix find, but only in the GNU find), but you can simply use `-name`, and then see the program it generates. From there, you can modify the program to use the Perl expressions you want in your regex. In the end, you'll get a small Perl script that will do the file directory find you want.

Otherwise, try using `-regextype posix-extended` which pretty much match **most** of Perl's regex expressions. You can't use look arounds, but you can probably find something that does work.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the find man page](http://ss64.com/bash/find.html) the find regex uses per default emacs regex. And according to http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html emacs is GNU ERE and that does not support look arounds.

You can try a different `-regextype` like @l0b0 suggested, but also the Posix flavours seems to not support this feature.

Answer (score 3):

What you've got looks like a Perl regex. Try with a different `-regextype`, and tweak the regex accordingly:

> Changes the regular expression syntax
>   understood by  -regex  and -iregex
>   tests which occur later on the command
>   line.  Currently-implemented types are
>   emacs (this is  the  default), 
>   posix-awk, posix-basic, posix-egrep
>   and posix-extended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ls ????-??aid-?????-INA.txt
```

Comment: I want everything except ...aid... files ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try simple script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *INA.txt
do
    match=$(echo "${file%INA.txt}" | sed  -r 's/^\w{4}-\w{5}-\w{5}-$/found/')
    [ $match == "found" ] && echo "$file"
done
```